# Scrapy does not crawl after first page

Tags: scrapy

I am hitting a dead end with this problem I am having for 4 days. I want to crawl "http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers". On each job listing page (i.e. http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers?page=2) I go inside each job link and get the job title. I have this working so far.

Now, I am trying to make the spider go to next job listing page (i.g. from http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers?page=2 to http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers?page=3 and crawl all the jobs). My crawl rule does not work and I have no clues what is wrong, what is missing. Please help.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem

class LedcorSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ledcor"
    allowed_domains = ["www.ledcor.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers"]


    rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers\?page=\d",),restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pager"]/a',)), follow=True),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("http://www.ledcor.com/job\?(.*)",)),callback="parse_items")
    ]

def parse_items(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = CraigslistSampleItem()
    item['title'] = hxs.select('//h1/text()').extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
    item['link'] = response.url
    return item
```

here is Items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class CraigslistSampleItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    link = Field()
    desc = Field()
```

Here is Pipelines.py

```
class CraigslistSamplePipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

Updated: (@blender suggestion) It doesnt crawl

```
rules = [
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r"http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers\?page=\d",),restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pager"]/a',)), follow=True),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("http://www.ledcor.com/job\?(.*)",)),callback="parse_items")
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `restrict_xpaths` argument is wrong. Remove it and it will work.

```
$ scrapy shell http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers

In [1]: from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

In [2]: lx = SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers\?page=\d",),restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pager"]/a',))

In [3]: lx.extract_links(response)
Out[3]: []

In [4]: lx = SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers\?page=\d",))

In [5]: lx.extract_links(response)
Out[5]: 
[Link(url='http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers?page=1', text=u'', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers?page=2', text=u'2', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers?page=3', text=u'3', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers?page=4', text=u'4', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers?page=5', text=u'5', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers?page=6', text=u'6', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers?page=7', text=u'7', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers?page=8', text=u'8', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers?page=9', text=u'9', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.ledcor.com/careers/search-careers?page=10', text=u'10', fragment='', nofollow=False)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the question mark and use a raw string for the regex:

```
r"http://www\.ledcor\.com/careers/search-careers\?page=\d"
```

Otherwise, it looks for URLs like `...careerspage=2` and `...carrerpage=3`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but my spider does not crawl after the start_url

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), follow=True, callback="parse_items")]
```

Also, suitable changes need to be made in `pipeline.py` and do paste pipeline and items code.

Comment: my spider crawl all links with your rule. I dont want that.